# flutter unit test: verify a method is called or not

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I have this class :

```
class Repository extends IRepository {
  Repository(RRGraphQL client) : super(client: client);

  @override
  Future<GraphQLResponse<PasswordSendToken$Mutation>> getResetPasswordToken(String email) {
    return client.artemis!.execute(
      .....
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to test that does `getResetPasswordToken` method call or not :

so this is my test:

```
class RepoMoc extends Mock implements Repository {}

void main() {

  Repository repo = RepoMoc();
  test("repo", (){
    verify(() => repo.getResetPasswordToken).called(1);
  });
}
```

But I got this error :

```
package:test_api                          fail
package:mocktail/src/mocktail.dart 519:7  _makeVerify.<fn>
test/common/repository_test.dart 18:11    main.<fn>

Used on a non-mocktail object
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching this:

```
Repository repo = RepoMoc();
```

To one of these:

```
final repo = RepoMoc();
RepoMoc repo = RepoMoc();
IRepository repo = RepoMoc();
```

Add this (or whatever you want it to answer for the remainder of your code to work):

```
when(person.getResetPasswordToken).thenAnswer((_) async {...});
```

Comment: I select `RepoMoc repo = RepoMoc();` but I still got same error

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to mock the method.